# Merging array based on a single array item

Tags: php, merge

I have created a defaults array, and I am trying to replace the values in the array based on the `rating` from the defaults array and the database items that get returned. I am doing this so that if not all `ratings` in the database get returned I have a default value.

So, when this gets ran, I get a final list of `9` items, as the values in the database just get appended to the list but never replaced.

```
$ratings['results'] = array_merge([
    ['rating'=>5, 'rating_count'=>0, 'percent'=>0, 'average'=>0],
    ['rating'=>4, 'rating_count'=>0, 'percent'=>0, 'average'=>0],
    ['rating'=>3, 'rating_count'=>0, 'percent'=>0, 'average'=>0],
    ['rating'=>2, 'rating_count'=>0, 'percent'=>0, 'average'=>0],
    ['rating'=>1, 'rating_count'=>0, 'percent'=>0, 'average'=>0],
], $ratings['results']);
```

Here are the database items:

```
array(1) {
    ["results"]=>
    array(4) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#260 (4) {
        ["rating"]=>
        int(3)
        ["rating_count"]=>
        int(2)
        ["percent"]=>
        string(7) "50.0000"
        ["average"]=>
        string(6) "3.0000"
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#261 (4) {
        ["rating"]=>
        int(4)
        ["rating_count"]=>
        int(1)
        ["percent"]=>
        string(7) "25.0000"
        ["average"]=>
        string(6) "4.0000"
        }
        [2]=>
        object(stdClass)#262 (4) {
        ["rating"]=>
        int(5)
        ["rating_count"]=>
        int(1)
        ["percent"]=>
        string(7) "25.0000"
        ["average"]=>
        string(6) "5.0000"
        }
        [3]=>
        object(stdClass)#263 (4) {
        ["rating"]=>
        NULL
        ["rating_count"]=>
        int(4)
        ["percent"]=>
        string(8) "100.0000"
        ["average"]=>
        string(6) "3.7500"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the final json response (Note: The item where rating = null is a summary column):

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "rating": 5,
            "rating_count": 0,
            "percent": 0,
            "average": 0
        },
        {
            "rating": 4,
            "rating_count": 0,
            "percent": 0,
            "average": 0
        },
        {
            "rating": 3,
            "rating_count": 0,
            "percent": 0,
            "average": 0
        },
        {
            "rating": 2,
            "rating_count": 0,
            "percent": 0,
            "average": 0
        },
        {
            "rating": 1,
            "rating_count": 0,
            "percent": 0,
            "average": 0
        },
        {
            "rating": 3,
            "rating_count": 2,
            "percent": "50.0000",
            "average": "3.0000"
        },
        {
            "rating": 4,
            "rating_count": 1,
            "percent": "25.0000",
            "average": "4.0000"
        },
        {
            "rating": 5,
            "rating_count": 1,
            "percent": "25.0000",
            "average": "5.0000"
        },
        {
            "rating": null,
            "rating_count": 4,
            "percent": "100.0000",
            "average": "3.7500"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working this way. You have numeric arrays, and `array_merge`:

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.
>   [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Apart from that, your `defaults` is a multidimensional array, and `results` is an array of objects, so some conversion is required.

You can do something like this:

```
// fill resulting array with default values
$result = [
    ['rating'=>5, 'rating_count'=>0, 'percent'=>0, 'average'=>0],
    ['rating'=>4, 'rating_count'=>0, 'percent'=>0, 'average'=>0],
    ['rating'=>3, 'rating_count'=>0, 'percent'=>0, 'average'=>0],
    ['rating'=>2, 'rating_count'=>0, 'percent'=>0, 'average'=>0],
    ['rating'=>1, 'rating_count'=>0, 'percent'=>0, 'average'=>0],
];

// index results from the database to speed it up a bit
$indexed = [];
foreach($ratings['results'] as $rating) { 
    // be careful, if you have same rating from the db, only the last one counts
    $indexed[$rating->rating] = (array)$rating;
};

//merge line by line
array_walk(
    $result, 
    function(&$row, $key, $data) {
        if(isset($data[$row['rating']])) {
            $row = array_merge($row, $data[$row['rating']]);
        };
    },
    $indexed
);
```